# How to redirect to an Action when using filterContext.Result?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my OnActionExecuting event I want to redirect to a controller action method, but it seems I have to pass URL.

I don't want to hardcode a url, especially when I don't know the root URL i.e. it could be a subdomain or something.

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/home/contact");
```

Is there some overload that I am missing that I can do a redirect to action?

Answer (score 8):

I think you should be able to get a `UrlHelper`.

```
var Url = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
var url =  Url.Action("Contact", "Home");
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url);
```

Or you could use a `RedirectToRouteResult` and name your route. (This seems like a better answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could instantiate a `UrlHelper` instance and let that create the URL's for you.

Answer (score 0):

like this;

```
 if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled) return;

        Exception ex = filterContext.Exception;

        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/HataVer.cshtml"
        };

        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;



        return;
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try using this:

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "NameOfYourAction" controller = "NameOfYourController" }));
```